# Amazon EC2 Instance - Where is my file after I've uploaded it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started a Linux instance and uploaded a python file. When I SSH into my instance, it says that the file can not be found:

```
python: can't open file 'file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried finding the /var/www/html/ folder as suggested by a google search, but /var/www does not exist.

The original command I used was:

```
scp -i /path/my-key-pair.pem /path/SampleFile.txt ec2-user@\[2001:db8:1234:1a00:9691:9503:25ad:1761\]:~
```

Which seems to have went successfully, because there was no output / error message after I uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

@jbpib27 According to the command that you have shared above, your uploaded file would be in `home` directory of the instance .
To go to instance's home directory, run the following command:

```
cd ~
```

or

```
cd /home/ec2-user
```

Your uploaded file will be in your instance's home directory because in the scp command, you have put `~` after `:` which is a short for your instance home directory.

`ec2-user@\[2001:db8:1234:1a00:9691:9503:25ad:1761\]:~`